# How do I get a chart for a count of values in 3 bar chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph, pivot, bar-chart

I have a survey that is sent out to customer. The survey has 3 questions with 3 options to choose from:

1. Not Satisfied
2. Satisfied and
3. Very Satisfied.

The results data looks something like this:

```
Question 1      Question 2      Question 3      Date
Not Satisfied   Satisfied       Satisfied       04/07/2017
Satisfied       Satisfied       Satisfied       04/07/2017
Satisfied       Satisfied       Very Satisfied  04/07/2017
Not Satisfied   Satisfied       Satisfied       04/07/2017
Very Satisfied  Satisfied       Satisfied       04/07/2017
Not Satisfied   Very Satisfied  Satisfied       05/07/2017
Satisfied       Satisfied       Very Satisfied  05/07/2017
Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  05/07/2017
Very Satisfied  Satisfied       Satisfied       06/07/2017
Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  Satisfied       06/07/2017
Not Satisfied   Satisfied       Satisfied       06/07/2017
Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  06/07/2017
Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  Satisfied       06/07/2017
```

How do I get a 3 bar chart indicating the 3 questions that will show the counts of the number of 'Not Satisfied', 'Satisfied' and 'Very Satisfied' values?

**I would like my chart to look something like this:**

```
 |
 |   Q1  Q2  Q3         Q1  Q2  Q3          Q1  Q2  Q3
 |       ___ ___                            ___ ___ ___
5|   ___|   |___|                          |   |   |___|
4|  |___|   |   |       ___ ___ ___        |   |   |   |
3|  |   |   |   |      |___|___|   |       |   |___|   |
2|  |___|   |   |      |___|   |___|       |___|   |   |
1|  |   |   |   |      |   |   |   |       |   |   |   |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
     04/07/2017         05/07/2017          06/07/2017
```

I tried making a Pivot Table but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: Hi there. Just a quick aside: we like posts to be succinct here. If you can omit "Can someone help me please", " Thanks in advance", "Any help will be appreciated", "I was hoping someone can help" (etc) that would be great. It will save volunteers some work in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Also, the community has discussed whether home-made tags in titles are OK, and has decided that we prefer titles to be [ordinary sentences written in natural English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you add another table with some formulas.  It can get a little wonky to set up, but it works.

First, let's create some named ranges.

For the Question 1 results (results only, don't include the headers), call those `Question_1_results`.  Question 2 results, `Question_2_results`, and finally the Question 3 results name `Question_3_results`.

For the dates, just call the named range `dates`.

Now set up this table:

[image]

(Note: Row `17` is to help with the formula. You'll just be using `B18:K22` for the chart.  Row `18` does have merged cells, which I usually shy away from, but you need those here to get the chart's `X Axis` to look right.)

In `C20`, enter this formula. Then you can copy it to all those blank cells in the range `C20:K22`

```
=COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$14,C$17,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(C$19," ","_")&"_results"),$B20)
```

[image]

And finally, simply highlight your new table, go to Insert --> Stacked Column Chart:

[image]

Comment: This really helped. Thank you. I've marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in a format that is not easy to work with, but luckily since it is only a few options, it should be easy to manipulate.

You could create 3 new columns labeled Question 1 to 3.
Under each you could do 3 countif formulas

i.e. assuming Question 1 is in column A   =COUNTIF(A:A,"Satisfied"), then =COUNTIF(A:A,"Very Satisfied")

repeat for question 2 and question 3

Once you create a table that way, you can simply select it and insert a stacked bar chart.  I hope that makes helps.

Comment: Not sure why but that didn't quite work.The formula I used was: COUNTIF(A2:A37,"Not Satisfied"), then =COUNTIF(A2:A37,"Satisfied")

Comment: This should be separate formulas.  For example, in cell F2, you might have =COUNTIF(A2:A37,"Not Satisfied")      In column F3, you would then have another formula =COUNTIF(A2:A37,"Satisfied")