# How to replace a dot with a space in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, replace, expression

I have a name field that in a report built in report builder. The name field sometimes shows a '..' or sometimes shows '. .'. I would like to Replace that using an expression in SSRS.

I've tried the expression below. But that didn't work:

```
=Fields!MyField.Value.ToString().Replace(". .", "")
```

Comment: Regarding home-made "tags" added at the start or the end of titles, the community [prefers questions without this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often). If you can write your titles in ordinary, flowing English, that is generally thought to be the clearest approach. I have given this advice [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46185525).

Answer (score 1):

The expression is you want is

```
=replace(Fields!MyField.Value.ToString(),".","")
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to do this in SQL if possible.

REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )